# why doesn't XMLTYPE.getClobVal() work on 9i like on 11g?

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

So on 11g I can execute the following plsql without any problems:

```
DECLARE
  lob1 CLOB;

BEGIN

  SELECT e.xml_col.getClobVal() INTO lob1 FROM "XML"."XML_TABLE" e WHERE KEY_COL=3 ;
  DBMS_LOB.APPEND(lob1, 'is a test node</test>');

END;
```

But on 9i the same code results in a ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified error.

Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Is the exception coming from that dbms_lob.append call?  It's supposed to take two LOBs but you're passing a string literal as the second parameter.  Is there maybe a change in the implicit type conversion from 9i to 11g?  I don't have any 9i databases anymore to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon, but I can't reproduce it on my 9.2.0.1.0, this example works flawlessly:

```
declare
  fOrigXml XmlType := XmlType(
'<RootNode>
  <ChildNodes>
  </ChildNodes>
</RootNode>');
   t clob;

begin
  select fOrigXml.getClobVal() into t from dual;
  dbms_lob.append(t, '4343');
  dbms_output.put_line(t);
end;
/
```

Could you please try this one and reply whether this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but you can try to open your clob variable first:

```
DBMS_LOB.createTemporary(lob1, cache => FALSE);
DBMS_LOB.Open(lob1, DBMS_LOB.lob_readwrite);
```